# scroll primefaces datatable vertically

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using primefaces 3.5 and primefaces extension, I have a datatable and when I put the  property scrollable = "true" the scroll appears in my table correctly but also appears in my pe: layoutPane, I hope to help me. thanks

I want the vertical scroll only appears in the datatable.

```
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="registro"
                        value="#     {regManualGrupalController.regManualDataModel}"
                        selection="#{regManualGrupalController.regSeleccionados}"
                        emptyMessage="Asistencia(s) no encontrada(s)" style="width:1100px;margin:1%;height:320px"
                        widgetVar="alumnosTable" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="320">
                        <!--  -->
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Asistencias Docentes
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px">
                        </p:column>
```

It is noteworthy that the more increases the size of the scroll in the datatable, but increases the size of the scroll pane

Answer (score 0):

Add a `id` to your `<pe:layoutPane>` and set it's `overflow` css property to `hidden`.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I need to scroll vertically when a lower resolution, so you can see the full content.